# Xcode- is there a good way to deprecate APIs without spamming output?

Tags: xcode, deprecated

I write foundational code for a large team of developers, and if I don't deprecate something it'll never stop being used.  However, deprecation warnings are somewhat annoying and get in the way of more important errors/warnings.

Has anyone out there come up with a decent solution for this type of problem?

To elaborate:

- Large code base with many developers
- Many places where deprecated API are being used
- Those places cannot be updated immediately (we're talking months to years)
- Deprecations are still needed to ensure that developers do not use deprecated APIs.
- The deprecations should not interfere with *real* warnings/errors.

Comment: the way I see it deprecation warnings are *supposed* to be annoying. you don't specify in your question what exactly you feel the problem is. do you just not want the deprecation warnings? (you can turn them off)

Comment: anyway, I feel like your options consist of 1. move away from the deprecated functions and 2. suppress the deprecated warnings. for #2 you can just disable them for "release" builds if you want, would that make them less "annoying"?

Comment: I've elaborated on my question a little bit.

Comment: there is no way to make warnings "less in your face" than to turn off the specific warning. As I stated before, you can setup a custom build mode that has these warnings enabled/disabled so you can switch between configurations with and without deprecated warnings.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the `__attribute__` macro that will give compiler warnings whenever a deprecated method is used (this is how apple does it). Just place the `__attribute__` after the declaration of whatever you want to deprecate. Like so:

```
-(void)someDeprecatedMethod __attribute__((deprecated("Use some other method instead")));
```

This will cause a compiler warning where ever your deprecated method is used. This is ideal for you because it will place warnings at any existing use of the method, so that they can be fixed when the opportunity arises, but (hopefully) other developers won't continue to use it as the warning will immediately appear when they do. There is also no output added, just compile time checking.

Comment: I know how to deprecate things.  I want to deprecate them in a less in-your-face manner.  See my updated question.

Comment: A warning seems like the least in-your-face method without letting it go unnoticed. Anyone can ignore logs, and you can't remove the method without requiring everyone to refactor. If your project is already drowned with warnings, that is an issue in itself that you should attempt to resolve so that meaningful warnings (like deprecations) get noticed by developers.

Comment: Also, using this directive makes your warnings something that can be disabled separately from other warnings. `-Wno-deprecated` I think?